# wordpress include local root php file

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I have a child theme functions.php that I am trying to have include a few local domain files , through the use of short codes, that live outside of the Wordpress file structure.

I cant seem to find whats going wrong. Anyone have any pointers?

child theme functions.php

```
<?php
// localhost path
define('WEB_ROOT', 'http://www.example.com/');

// includes
function filePost() {
    include WEB_ROOT.'/include/file.php';
}
add_shortcode('fileShortCode', 'filePost');
?>
```

Comment: include means to include something i.e. libraries into the script or your theme what could be necessary for your theme whereas shortcode display output of functions. Please check http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API to understand shortcode as well as http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php for php include.

Answer (score 0):

With default PHP settings you can't include files from external sources, which `http://example.com` is.

To be able to do that, you'd need to change [allow-url-include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) setting. But perhaps the only thing you have to do, is not referring to a URL, but rather to a local path? This you can retrieve by using Wordpress function [plugin_dir_path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path)

Comment: I have allow-url-include on but still can not get the file to work.